# CSS media calls don't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries, email-validation

I am trying to get the following media calls to work in this email design. Sorry for posting a lot of code. When I get below 660px, the large logo disappears but a smaller logo does not appear in its place. The logo space is blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Our Vineyard</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
                table.container { width: 480px !important; }
                td.logo img { display: none; }
                td.logo { background: #c2ca19 url(../../My Site/Images/logo_medium.gif) no-repeat 10px 10px; height: 45px; }
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 510px) {
                table.container { width: 100% !important; }
                table.container td { border: none !important; }
                td.logo { background: #2cca19 url(../../My Site/Images/logo_small.gif) no-repeat center 10px; height:32px; }
            }

        </style>
    </head> 
    <body bgcolor = "#efe1b0" background="../../My Site/Images/banner_large.jpg">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor = "#efe1b0">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <table class="container" width="640" align="center" border ="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td valign="top" class ="logo" bgcolor="#ffffff"  style="padding: 10px 20px 0px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border_right: 1px solid #dbc064; border_top: 1px solid #dbc064;">
        <a href ="#"><img style= "margin-left:-15px" src="../../My Site/Images/logo_large.gif" alt="Our Vineyard" width="585" height="45" border="0"></a>   
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan="2" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="headline" style="padding: 15px 20px 5px 30px; border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 22px;"><h1 style="margin 0px 0px 15px 0px; font-weight: normal;  font-size: 32px; color: #723c7F;">Main Heading Here</h1>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#f5f2e5" class="banner" style="border-left: 1px solid #dbc064; border-right: 1px solid #dbc064;">
        <img src="../../My Site/Images/banner_large.jpg" width="638" height="180" alt="Photo of our Vineyard"></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I initially thought the issue was due to the usage of deprecated html attributes. Specifically, I thought that bgcolor might be overriding your css rule. But I've ran your code and changed out the images to lorem images and everything appears to work fine. Are you sure that you are specifying the correct location of your image?

Answer (score 2):

You missed to add view port meta, add below meta on your head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And you should have your standard css as well.

Comment: Thank you. I put the view port meta in, but it didn't make any difference. Where do I put standard css? Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Try adding your standard css above media queries.

Comment: Hello RaJesh. How do I add standard css above media queries. Sorry, I am very new to this.

Comment: refer this example https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1

Comment: @PhillipMoney and these are general things to follow. If not working, don't forget to check image src and all as per Jay Watson's comment below.